# Can I use a rightSwipeGestureRecognizer for a content page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that I am looking at. Currently it has this:

C# code

```
namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class PhrasesPage : ContentPage
    public PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame = new PhrasesFrame();

    public PhrasesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        phrasesStackLayout.Children.Add(phrasesFrame);
```

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
        x:Class="Japanese.PhrasesPage"
        x:Name="PhraseContentPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="phrasesStackLayout">
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And then inside of that:

C# code

```
namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
```

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Japanese.PhrasesFrame" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" HasShadow="false">
    <StackLayout x:Name="phrasesFrameStackLayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

There's a custom renderer for the frame that implements rightSwipeGestureRecognizer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PhrasesFrame),         typeof(PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
public class PhrasesFrameCustomRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer leftSwipeGestureRecognizer;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer rightSwipeGestureRecognizer;
    PhrasesFrame frame;
    bool rightSwipeEnabled = false;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        frame = Element as PhrasesFrame;

        rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
        rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
        rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.AddTarget((obj) =>
        { });
```

My question is, do I need to have a frame inside of the content page to implement a SwipeGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I can't see any 'custom renderer' in the code above. And I can't understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code could also work on any given other element. Since you're currently inheriting the `CustomRenderer` from `FrameRenderer` it will only work on `Frame` objects and more specifically `PhrasesFrame` objects (as defined in the `ExportRenderer` attribute. You can easily change this to e.g. `PageRenderer` like such:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyContentPage), typeof(ContentPageRenderer))]

namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
```

You could then change every piece of code referencing the `Frame` in this renderer to reference to `ContentPage` instead and it will probably work. That does mean that **every** `ContentPage` object gets this functionality, so you will most likely have to create your own object inheriting from `ContentPage` and apply the `CustomRenderer` to that.

```
public class MyContentPage : ContentPage
{

}
```

And update your XAML accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<local:MyContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
        x:Class="Japanese.PhrasesPage"
        x:Name="PhraseContentPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="phrasesStackLayout">

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</local:MyContentPage>
```

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean by "you will most likely have to create your own object inheriting from ContentPage and apply the CustomRenderer to that.: